# Removing a todo from todo list in react

Tags: reactjs, function, filter

I am creating this todo list app, but I can't seem to find out how to make the react icon when clicked to delete that value that it's next to.

I tried doing this:

```
const click = () => {
    setTodos(todos => todos.filter((item) => item.id));
  }

  return (
    <>
    <h2>Your Todos</h2>
     <NewTodo onAdd={(newTodo) => setTodos([...todos, newTodo])} />
      <ul>
    {visibleTodos.map((todo) => (
      <li key={todo.id}>
        {todo.text}
        <button onClick={click}><AiFillDelete /></button>
          </li>    
        ))}
      </ul>
     </>
    );
   }
```

When I clicked the icon next to the todo it got deleted, but when I tried deleting another value it didn't work. I could only delete one todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this meant to filter?:

```
todos.filter((item) => item.id)
```

This is returning all items which *have an ID*, which is probably all of them, no?  Generally you would filter items which *match a condition*.  For example, all items which don't match a specific ID:

```
todos.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
```

So then you'd need a value for `id`, which can be passed to the function:

```
const click = (id) => {
```

And then you'd just need to pass the ID to the function:

```
onClick={() => click(todo.id)}
```